# When do you make bonus attacks from haste?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, attack

When things such as haste, speed, or the ki ability for an extra attack.

I know under combat rules that you take your attacks in order of base attack bonus, does that apply in this case as well or could you take these extra attacks at the end?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The general rule, as you say, is that highest BAB goes first, and the haste attacks (or what have you) have the same BAB as your highest attack.

Nothing in the description of haste counters this general rule, so it still applies.

In case it ever matters, you (the player) decide if the haste attack comes after or before the first BAB attack.